# Using REST design properly - Categories and Subcategories

Tags: mysql, database, rest, restful-url

*I have two question on basic `REST` concepts.*

**QUESTION 1**:  Categories

So I have a list of Categories I want to show from a database.

`SELECT * from categories`

Currently, I use this REST desgin:  `/api/v1/categories/`

Is that proper?

I have also seen `/api/v1/categories/list/`  -- or is this preferred?  (If so, then what would a simple `/categories` call display then?   (Or would the proper way then be `/api/v1/category/list` where `category` is singular and adding `list` will show you all categories -- this way a call to `/category` would allow veiwing info on just one?)

**QUESTION 2**:  Subcategories.  (Think "Seinfeld" as a subcategory of "Television".)

`SELECT * FROM subcategories" WHERE category_id = {id}`

The `id` above might be the Television Category where I want to get specific shows listed.

Would I do `/api/v1/categories/{id}/` for the Subcategory with the subcat_id? Would I have to use parameters instead like `/Categories?id={id}/`

How would this relationship work?

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't know if there is any "properly" answer.  *You decide* what works best for you and your application.  Now, having said that, I think that you *should* arrange for your URLs to read "left to right," and that there probably only be one "sort of thing" that appears in any given slot.  For instance, I probably wouldn't use `/api/v1/categories/xyzzy` (where "xyzzy") is a category-ID, *and* `/api/v1/categories/list`. *(The Marketing Department invents a category named `list` and now your code is broken ...)*  And above all: Be Consistent.  Stick to ONE way.

Comment: (In the above, I might instead use, say, `/api/v1/categories/item/xyzzy`.  Now, the URL-string reads cleanly from left-to-right, and the two possible values for the fourth item (in this case) are, say: `list` or `item`, such that the presence of any other string in that position indicates a malformed URL (client error).  And *every other* URL follows that same pattern.  I have also seen RESTful APIs that *also* supported JSON, and these had a clearly-defined URL-name which indicated that JSON data must accompany it.)  Think carefully, plan for the future, and Be Consistent.

Comment: @MikeRobinson  Thanks for the feedback.  I have three levels deep (where each level can give you a list).  Categories->Subcategories->Items.  For example, Television->Seinfeld->Kramer.  If I can ask for your opinion, what would be an appropriate url in this case?  Do I need to show three levels deep?

Answer (score 1):

My answers are based on "pragmatic REST".

> QUESTION 1: Categories

If you go with plural or singular form then I would suggest sticking with it and not jump between singular and plural... this is subjective.

If you go with singular form, then the `list` path action sounds applicable.  If you go with plural then I think it is more subjective... IMHO `list` removes ambiguity and I would prefer it.

> QUESTION 2: Subcategories. (Think "Seinfeld" as a subcategory of "Television".)

IMHO sub-category sounds like a separate resource.  I think it should have its own path element.

> Would I do /api/v1/categories/{id}/ for the Subcategory with the subcat_id? Would I have to use parameters instead like /Categories?id={id}/

I think that `/api/v1/subcategories/{id}/` is more popular.  But one thing that is becoming more popular is searching criteria.  ID might just be one of many search criteria.  If you see yourself adding search criteria then `/api/v1/subcategories/?id={id}` or `/api/v1/subcategories/?filter={some_search_string}` where you decide how that search string is parsed.

The most important thing to consider is that you are able to grow (extend) your API without changing these initial decisions you are making now.  Its easy to add to an API but harder to alter existing API design once it is being used.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  It sounds like it is more flexible than I envisioned.

Comment: Correct.  REST is not a protocol like TCP or HTTP.  That opens it up for interpretation and subjectivity.  In fact the REST that was originaly conceptualized is not followed exactly.  That's why terms like "pragmatic REST" came up.  Checkout this cool ebook from apigee.  It can attest to some of the variety you see in REST.  https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The URI structure is an implementation detail, it does not matter by REST as long as your service fulfills the uniform interface constraint, which is about applying the relevant standards. In your case the URI structure must fulfill the URI standard and you have to use a hypermedia format, which contains hyperlinks. So in your case `/api/v1/sdfh34gsv/123regf3` would be completely okay as long as it is in a hyperlink and there is sufficient metadata available to understand what that hyperlink does. E.g. with HAL+JSON:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "/api/v1/docs/rels/category": {
            "href": "/api/v1/sdfh34gsv/123regf3",
            "title": "Television"
        }
    }
}
```

By processing such a response the client will recognize the "/api/v1/docs/rels/category" link relation, so it will know that it is a hyperlink to a category, which title is "Television" and the details of the category can be retrieved by following the link. If the client does not know the `/api/v1/docs/rels/category` link relation, then it can dereference the URI and and probably it will get some description in RDF, which it can use to display the hyperlink in a more basic form. Ofc, if developers dereference the same URI, they can get a HTML description of the link relation.

By most of the REST services this does not happen, because they use vendor specific MIME types and probably plain JSON, which violates the HATEOAS constraint, but I guess it is more practical in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
async getAllCategorySubCategoryAndGroupCategoryDetail(): Promise < CategoryDetails[] > {
    try {
        let categoryGroupQuery = `SELECT shrt_category_groups.id as categoryGroupId, 
                                          shrt_category_groups.category_group_name as categoryGroupName,
                                          concat('${ENV.IMG_SERVER}',shrt_category_groups.category_group_image) AS categoryGroupImage,
                                          shrt_category_groups.is_active as isActive,
                                          shrt_category_groups.sort_order as sortOrder
                                      FROM shrt_category_groups where shrt_category_groups.is_active = '1' `;

        let categoryGroupList = await pool.query(categoryGroupQuery);
        if (categoryGroupList.length > 0) {
            let categoryListQuery = `SELECT shrt_categories.id as categoryId,
                                                  shrt_categories.category_name as categoryName,
                                                  shrt_categories.category_image as categoryImage,
                                                  shrt_categories.is_active as isActive,
                                                  shrt_categories.category_group_id as categoryGroupId
                                             FROM shrt_categories where shrt_categories.is_active = '1'`;

            let categoryList = await pool.query(categoryListQuery);
            let subcategoryQuery = `SELECT shrt_sub_categories.id as subCategoryId,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.is_active as isActive,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.subcategory_commission as commission,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.commission_type as commissionType,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.sub_category_name as subCategoryName,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.category_id as categoryId 
                                            FROM shrt_sub_categories where shrt_sub_categories.is_active = '1'`;

            let subCategoryList = await pool.query(subcategoryQuery);

            const getCategory = (categoryGroupId: any) => {
                return categoryList.filter((cat: any) => cat.categoryGroupId == categoryGroupId)
            }

            const getSubCategory = (categoryId: any) => {
                return subCategoryList.filter((subCategory: any) => subCategory.categoryId == categoryId)
            }

            let mergeData = categoryGroupList.map((catG: any) => {
                return { ...catG,
                    category: getCategory(catG.categoryGroupId).map((cat) => {
                        return { ...cat,
                            subCategory: getSubCategory(cat.categoryId)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            return mergeData;
        } else {
            return categoryGroupList;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "categoryGroupId": 1,
         "categoryGroupName": "Cloud",
         "categoryGroupImage": null,
         "isActive": "1",
         "sortOrder": null,
         "category": [
            {
               "categoryId": 1,
               "categoryName": "Kinder & Baby",
               "categoryImage": null,
               "isActive": "1",
               "categoryGroupId": 1,
               "subCategory": [
                  {
                     "subCategoryId": 17,
                     "isActive": "1",
                     "commission": null,
                     "commissionType": null,
                     "subCategoryName": "Shirts",
                     "categoryId": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "subCategoryId": 20,
                     "isActive": "1",
                     "commission": null,
                     "commissionType": null,
                     "subCategoryName": "Jacken",
                     "categoryId": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "subCategoryId": 21,
                     "isActive": "1",
                     "commission": null,
                     "commissionType": null,
                     "subCategoryName": "Organic Collection",
                     "categoryId": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "subCategoryId": 22,
                     "isActive": "1",
                     "commission": null,
                     "commissionType": null,
                     "subCategoryName": "Baby",
                     "categoryId": 1
                  },
                  {
                     "subCategoryId": 23,
                     "isActive": "1",
                     "commission": null,
                     "commissionType": null,
                     "subCategoryName": "Hoodies & Sweatshirts",
                     "categoryId": 1
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```